# IntelliJ cannot find MySQL JDBC driver

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, servlets

I have added MySQL JDBC driver but I keep getting the following error: `No suitable driver found for jdbc`.

Here's the code that I'm trying:

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp1", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Connected successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here are the project settings.

[image]
[image]

As soon as I add MySQL jar, one following problem appears:

[image]

I have tried all of the three options above, but I keep getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: You must include the jdbc driver in the artifact which you deploy to Tomcat. Otherwise Tomcat will not find it in the application classpath when it will deploy the application. Also make sure the jdbc driver class is actually present in this jar library.

Comment: @Andrey I noticed that when I add `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");` line then it works. But I have read that this line should not be required in the recent versions. Could it mean that I'm using some wrong version? or is there some other reason?